# Qt Application does not load driver QMYSQL and does not recompile to get accept new version of libsqlmysql.so

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, qt

I am working on desktop application using `Qt 5.4.0 GCC 64bit Opensource` on `Kubuntu 14.10` using kernel `Linux desktop001 3.16.0-30-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 12 22:06:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, which needs to connect to `mysql` database on my local server. Now, when I run the following code chunk:

```
CMainWindow::CMainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    this->ueSetPosDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL"));
}
```

then I get following error in QtCreator's console:

> QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded QSqlDatabase: available
>   drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7

Now, the current installation of `Qt` has following sql plugins:

```
user@desktop001:/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers$ ls -asl
total 944
  4 drwxrwxrwx  2 user user   4096 dec 19 12:35 .
  4 drwxrwxrwx 22 user user   4096 dec 19 12:36 ..
780 -rwxrwxrwx  1 user user 797480 dec  5 22:08 libqsqlite.so
 72 -rwxrwxrwx  1 user user  73576 dec  5 22:08 libqsqlmysql.so
 84 -rwxrwxrwx  1 user user  85808 dec  5 22:08 libqsqlpsql.so
user@desktop001:/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers$`
```

If I run `ldd -v libsqlmysql.so`, I get `libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => not found` suspicious dependency problem:

```
user@desktop001:/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers$ ldd -v libqsqlmysql.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff307b2000)
        libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => not found
        libQt5Sql.so.5 => /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007f055223f000)
        libQt5Core.so.5 => /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f0551b02000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f05517f3000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f055142e000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f055120f000)
        libicui18n.so.53 => /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicui18n.so.53 (0x00007f0550dc3000)
        libicuuc.so.53 => /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicuuc.so.53 (0x00007f0550a38000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0550833000)
        libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f0550631000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f0550429000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f0550119000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f054fe13000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f054fbfc000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f05526c0000)
        libicudata.so.53 => /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicudata.so.53 (0x00007f054e573000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f054e306000)

        Version information:
        ./libqsqlmysql.so:
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libmysqlclient_r.so.16 (libmysqlclient_16) => not found
                libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
                libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libQt5Sql.so.5:
                libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
                libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5:
                ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
                librt.so.1 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
                libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
                libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
                libdl.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
                libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
                libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
                libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
                libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.3.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
                libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
                libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.7) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.9) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6:
                ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
                libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
                libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_4.2.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
                libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
                libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.18) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
                ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
                ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0:
                ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
                ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
                ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicui18n.so.53:
                libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
                libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
                libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicuuc.so.53:
                libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
                libdl.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
                libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
                libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
                libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
                libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
                libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.7) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2:
                ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0:
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1:
                libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
                libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
                libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0:
                libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.7) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.9) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.8) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.10) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.15) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6:
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1:
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3:
                libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
user@desktop001:/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers$
```

After @hank's suggestion, I've checked the existence of `libmysqlclient.so` and here is result:

```
user@desktop001:~$ /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep mysql | cut -d\> -f2
 /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.7
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so
user@desktop001:~$
```

I have also added softlink from `libmysqlclient_r.so.16` to `libmysqlclient_r.so.16` via `sudo ln -s libmysqlclient_r.so.18 libmysqlclient_r.so.16` and then rerun `sudo ln -s libmysqlclient_r.so.18 libmysqlclient_r.so.16` and dependency is now found:

```
user@desktop001:/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers$ ldd libqsqlmysql.so
./libqsqlmysql.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.16: version `libmysqlclient_16' not found (required by ./libqsqlmysql.so)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4edfc000)
        libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.16 (0x00007f07a0403000)
        libQt5Sql.so.5 => /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007f07a01c3000)
        libQt5Core.so.5 => /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f079fa86000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f079f777000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f079f3b2000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f079f198000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f079ef94000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f079ed76000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f079ea6f000)
        libicui18n.so.53 => /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicui18n.so.53 (0x00007f079e623000)
        libicuuc.so.53 => /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicuuc.so.53 (0x00007f079e298000)
        libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f079e095000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f079de8d000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f079db7e000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f079d966000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f07a0b80000)
        libicudata.so.53 => /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicudata.so.53 (0x00007f079c2de000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f079c070000)
user@desktop001:/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers$
```

but there is a warning:`/libqsqlmysql.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.16: version`libmysqlclient_16`not found (required by ./libqsqlmysql.so)`

Ok, I've delete that symbolic link to mysql library and tried to recompiled Qt from scratch with `clear && ./configure -plugin-sql-mysql && make all && make install` and now I get following errors:
make[3]: Entering directory '/opt/Qt/5.4/Src/qtbase/src/platformsupport'
/opt/Qt/5.4/Src/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile platformsupport.pro
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: dbus

```
Makefile:479: recipe for target 'Makefile' failed
make[3]: *** [Makefile] Error 3
make[3]: Leaving directory '/opt/Qt/5.4/Src/qtbase/src/platformsupport'
Makefile:370: recipe for target 'sub-platformsupport-all' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-platformsupport-all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/Qt/5.4/Src/qtbase/src'
Makefile:48: recipe for target 'sub-src-all' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-src-all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/Qt/5.4/Src/qtbase'
Makefile:73: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-all' failed
make: *** [module-qtbase-all] Error 2
```

Why am I getting these errors?

Comment: Do you have `libmysqlclient_r.so.16` installed on your system?

Comment: @hank, I've upgraded my question

Comment: You ever figure this one out?